# GCM not receiving sometimes

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the java servlet with mysql. gcm works but sometimes it's not sending the messages to the device.

this is my code

```
    Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
    String mesg = "some messages";
    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(0)
            .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, mesg).build();
        for (MMemberModel member : memberModels) {
            if (member.userid != creatorId) {
                try {
                    try {
                        // System.out.println("regId: " + member.gcm);
                        sender.send(message, member.gcm, 1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can send and receive GCM messages sometimes,then there is no error in your project

ya, i also faced that problem i revised my code many times, and also raised a question in stackowerflow. but i cant found any error in my code.

But i received GCM message after 2 days.

its maybe problem with your phone or gcm server

Comment: also my time to live value is 0